# How to open Maven Spring web application?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I used to run a Spring web based application using a batch script (https://ibb.co/bXAfFL). But now i have to debug it because of a small bug. So, i imported source project using prom.xml to intelij editor. Yes maven clean/validate/package all running fine inside it . As in my batch script i have some arguments to pass to jar ,i created a run configuration and selected jar based application , gave jar path and also arguments . But now when i try run/debug it show a long log message and do not run. what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Just run the main class (the one that has the `main()` method) as a Java application.

Comment: You don't need a script to run a Spring web app in IntelliJ.  The IDE can run it for you.  How is it packaged?  If it's an executable JAR you can tell IntelliJ to run the main class.  If it's a WAR file you'll need Tomcat or a Java EE app server to deploy to. Either way your best bet is to let the IDE run it.